# Alternative word for TODO

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

As a programmer myself, I usually use the word 'todo' when I comment something on my code. The word is descriptive enough on that purpose, but I can hardly come up with any alternative words for it that I should use for a more *formal* usage (like presentations or reports).

More specifically, what I want to find is the alternative word that I can use instead of *TODO* on the presentation slide that looks like this;

```
* TODOs
  - Fix bugs on line X.
  - Improve the algorithm.
```

We usually use the word 'action items' to enumerate the tasks that are left to be solved, but is there any other alternative that is presumably less verbose or, even better, a single word?

Comment: I'm not too sure about what you asked, can you give us more context?

Comment: There is no such word as *todo*. There is a noun [*to-do*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/to%20do) (which means noisy and confused activity), and you can use *to-do list*, where *to-do* acts as an adjective. In your example, I would have headed it *Things To Do*.

Comment: @Kyle I added some details

Comment: @JasonBassford Actually I guess it's not a real word but sort of a dialect that's only used by computer people.

Comment: I use TODO for for missing code or features and FIXME for errors and problems that should be solved. For a presentation I would use something like _Open Topics_.

Answer (score 1):

If it is to be presented to other coders / programmers, especially if they are part of the project, then leave it as it is - they know exactly what it means.

Also it is a term easily searched for and found when working through the code to correct the code.